# Does not work query in spring data jpa

Tags: java, spring, jpa

simple query findByPost with List work fine, but method where return Page does not work. Project even starts.When remove this method , All fine ;)

```
@Repository
public interface CategoryRepository extends CrudRepository<Category, Long>,
                                            PagingAndSortingRepository<Category,Long> {

    @Query("select c from Category c inner join fetch c.posts cp where cp.id =?1")
    List<Category> findAllByPost(long postId);

    @Query("select c from Category c inner join fetch c.posts cp where cp.id =?1")
    Page<Category> findAllByPost(long postId, Pageable pageable);
}
```

Comment: what is Page for you ? in which package is it ? Cause, if i don't make a mistake, it's not in the JDK nor in Spring data

Comment: You can see return Type for method findAllByPost.  
I can use something like this and send one post object in list of posts, bat it is not nice i think
Page<Category> findAllByPosts(List<Post> posts,Pageable pageable);

Comment: my question was, from which package the class Page comes, for you ?

Comment: org.springframework.data.domain.Page;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont need to extend CrudRepository as PagingAndSortingRepository already does this. Change your signature to -

public interface CategoryRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `Page` creates two queries, one the original query and other for the count. The count query doesn't require `JOIN FETCH`. You can solve it by having `countQuery` attribute within `@Query` annotation. More details here:-

http://codingexplained.com/coding/java/spring-framework/fetch-query-not-working-spring-data-jpa-pageable